# Creating item using SharePoint web services

Tags: development, web-services

I need to create an item in a SharePoint list using Lists.UpdateListItems web service.
I have created a batch method and populate it with these fields.

```
<Field Name="ContentType">Document</Field>
<Field Name="FileLeafRef">??????</Field>
<Field Name="Title">Doc1</Field>
<Field Name="LookupColumn"></Field>
```

I don't know how the FileLeafRef format looks like. when i write Doc1.txt for example, the service returns an error.

Any one has an idea.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please, do not double post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117972/creating-item-using-sharepoint-web-services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FileLeafRef must contain the full path to the document.

But keep in mind that creating new documents in a doclib using Lists.UpdateListItems is not possible ([citation needed] && as far as i know)

Comment: Are you sure that the FileLeafRef must contain the full path of the document? Can you provide me a link that describes and explains the FileLeafRef field?

Comment: Hmmmz, The examples I found use FileRef instead of FileLeafRef. The examples on MSDN use it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems(v=office.12).aspx and here also the full path is used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372971/sharepoint-deleting-an-item-from-a-list-using-updatelistitems-webservice

Answer (score 1):

Maybe im wrong here, but i thought FileLeafRef only was used when query for items and not needed when creating them.

Comment: I need to set the item name. what field type should i choose?

Comment: What do you mean with the item name, the Title? Check out: http://geekswithblogs.net/WayneMagnum/archive/2008/03/27/sharepoint-list-webservice-to-insert-item.aspx maybe its to some help :)

Comment: No i need the name that is displayed when the user view the list. If i don't set it the created item name will be his id plus underscore dot three zeros (ex: 99_.000) and the display will be 99_

Comment: The document name yes, now im following. If i remember correctly the internal name is BaseName for the Name field

Comment: I tried it and got this error: 0x80070057 Bad parameter passed to Web Server Extensions.  Check the information you entered and try again.

Comment: Did a search: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/f135aaa2-3345-483f-ade4-e4fd597d50d4/ hope it helps you, have never upload documents that way myself :)